Microsoft 365 admin center REST API :: why User Principal Name & Display Name are IDs?
I'm getting extensive help from Sridevi and I noticed that the data that he is pulling they are including:

User Principal Name which is the e-mail of the user
Display Name: which are name and surname of the user


In the other hand the same endpoint is showing me an ID for those two columns:

But we are both pulling the data from the same endpoint:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D7')
Authorization: Bearer <token>

How is it possible that the same request is pulling different data?
